# npm install errors with Connect module

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, node.js-connect

I have installed all dependencies related with this project https://github.com/msfrisbie/mean-stripdown.git with the command `npm install`.

Then I got the next errors related only with connect@2.9.0 module:

```
 npm ERR! missing bytes@0.2.1 required by connect@2.9.0
 npm ERR! missing qs@0.6.5 required by connect@2.9.0
 npm ERR! missing uid2@0.0.2 required by connect@2.9.0 
 ...
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Given this facts, I have installed this modules one by one and the errors go away. But this is not the correct way to fix this problem. So....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you're trying to install requires *Express*, which requires *Connect@2.9.0*, which is unable to find the modules you're listing. Trying use `npm cache clean` and then reinstalling. If that doesn't work, you can alternately completely remove the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Ok you are right, but the npm cache clean did not work for me. So I installed the Connect@2.9.0 package alone then copy and paste it inside the node_modules folder of the Express module and it works. Thanks.